# Domain Model and "Business Logic" confusion

Tags: mvvm, architecture, domain-driven-design, business-logic, domain-model

Whenever I read an article about modern design pattern like MVVM or DDD I have trouble translating the example into the domains I am typically working on.

All these pattern come to the conclusion that domain models should exist in their own little bubble with no references to anything whatsoever, should not be exposed to the view for binding, should be POCOs/POJOs and contain the "business logic".

The question I always ask myself is: What should the domain model do then?

The answer is obviously "Handle business logic", but when I think about what that might be I'm having trouble finding *real world* examples.

For example: One typical example that always comes up are financial applications, where you could have a `BankAccount` entity which could have a `TransferMoneyTo(otherAccount)` function.
This sounds good in theory, but in the real world this application would not manage all the bank accounts of the world, but just accounts of one bank.
Therefore a real world application would have to *somehow* contact the other bank's server to initiate this transaction. This "somehow" is obviously a **service** to which the `BankAccount` is not allowed to have a reference to. This means that this would not be a very good example for an isolated domain model.

So far all examples I have read about where either like this, where the example only worked, because it neglected important details or trivial. By trivial I mean, the "business logic" just consisted of simple validation (e.g. required fields).

All this leads to an [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) (apart from validation perhaps), which is supposed to be a bad thing.

My question is: **What hides behind the term "business logic"** apart from validation, that would justify the need for a separate domain model?

Note: I know this depends on the domain you are working on, but I think at least some example where DDD would be actually useful would be appreciated.

Comment: I was also somewhat confused on this, but then came across this wonderful article. Might help your as well : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10746/Dude-where-s-my-business-logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What hides behind the term "business logic"

A lot of domain models reflect business processes and thus contain state machines, where you can transition things from a known valid state to another according to some rules. You get this kind of process in just about every business. Other domains can involve more complex internal algorithms and data transformations.

These hardly fall into the simplistic "*just validation*" category, unless you consider a railway company seat reservation system or a government's tax calculation process as "*validation*".

> This "somehow" is obviously a service to which the BankAccount is not
>   allowed to have a reference to

Regarding domains communicating with the outside world, it's not really their responsibility. Generally what you have is the domain emitting an event saying "this happened !" and the applicative context handles it and initiates the appropriate communications with external systems.

Orchestrating calls to internal and external subsystems so that data flows in, out and through an application is not domain logic, it's a technical application-level concern. Inversion of Control, in one form or another (events, DI, etc.), is usually key to keeping the domain unaware of this.

Comment: Ok, if you would have a `GetEmptySeatAtWindow(train)` and a `BookThisSeat(seat)` function for example, there would probably be some kind of non-trivial logic involved. Although I wouldn't know where to put these functions in DDD, because this Class would have to know everything that is required to perform these actions, because it is not allowed to pull further data... The tax calculation process would really benefit from DDD. I can see that. But it is kind of a niche.

Comment: The problem I have with these domain events is, that I don't know how the domain model keeps itself in a consistent state if it does not know, what happened in response to this event. The `BankAccount` for example is only allowed to withdraw money, if the receiving bank accepts the transaction. If something goes wrong the model would be inconsistent and the money would be gone forever, if the model has no knowledge of the outside world.

Comment: One key to DDD is to make domain concepts explicit in your code. I have absolutely zero knowledge in banking, but I guess you would model this as two states : TransactionPending and TransactionCompleted. The domain is kept aware of changes by the applicative layer around it.

Comment: Regarding the train example, DDD has Aggregates as single entry points for modification. All the data needed to decide and act must be either a) passed to the aggregate or b) contained inside it. Note that Aggregates are not a single class but a group of related classes. You can easily derive a design for seat reservation from this.

Comment: I just used the banking example, because everyone else does it. The main issue is how does the model keep itself consistent with the outside world it has no control over. Do you mean my model class has some property reflecting that a transaction was issued and maybe a method like `TransactionCompleted(transaction)` where all the business logic in case of success or failure is executed (i.e. the money is actually withdrawn).

Comment: I think I will have to look into Aggregates then... Maybe that will answer some of my questions.

Comment: Absolutely, the model cannot be **immediatley consistent** with the outside world, so we make it **eventually consistent** when the world gets back to us (key concept of eventual consistency here too).

Answer (score 2):

> This "somehow" is obviously a service to which the `BankAccount` is not
>   allowed to have a reference to. This means that this would not be a
>   very good example for an isolated domain model.

While the `BankAccount` doesn't have a reference in itself to this service, it can still interact with such a service.

For a more simple example, let's take the calculation of interest. The naive approach may be:

```
public BankAccount 
{
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public decimal Interest { get; set; }
    private public List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get { return transactions; } } 

    public decimal CalculateInterest() 
    {
        return Balance * Interest;
    }
}

// inside a service
BankAccount account = ...;
var interest = account.CalculateInterest();
account.Balance += interest;
account.AddTransaction(new Transaction() { Description = "Monthly Interest", Amount = interest });
```

Which is bad, cause now you have mixed responsibilities. Calculating the Interest isn't the focus of BankAccount class and it's now involved with multiple responsibilities like the calculation, which may change or depend on several factors.

```
public BankAccount 
{
    // private setters, so no one outside BankAccount can update it directly
    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }
    public AccountType AccountType { get; private set; } // assume business and private account
    private public List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    // return as "AsEnumerable" so user can't later cast it back to list and
    // directly add Transactions, skipping the AddTransaction method
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions { get { return transactions.AsEnumerable(); } } 

    public void CalculateInterest(IInterestCalculator calc) 
    {
        decimal interest = calc.CalculateInterest(this);
        this.AddTransaction(new Transaction() { Description = "Monthly Interest", Amount = interest });
    }

    public void AddTransaction(Transaction transaction) 
    {
        var newBalance = this.Balance + transaction.Balance;

        if(this.transaction.Amount < 0 && newBalance < this.Limit) 
        {
            // new balance would exceed the accounts limit
            throw new NotEnoughFundsException();
        }

        this.transactions.Add(transaction);
        this.Balance = newAmount;
    }
}

public interface IInterestCalculator 
{
    decimal CalculateInterest(Bankaccount);
}

public class DefaultAccountInterestCalculator : IInterestCalculator
{
    public decimal CalculateInterest(BankAccount account) 
    {
        // for sake of simplicity, inlined
        return account.Balance * 0.02;
    }
}
public class PremiumAccountInterestCalculator : IInterestCalculator 
{
    private const decimal Threshold = 10000m;
    public decimal CalculateInterest(BankAccount account) 
    {
        // Premium customers receive increased interest, above a certain threshold. 3% for the balance above the threshold of 10000 USD
        if(account.Balance > Threshold) 
        {
            return (decimal)((Threshold * 0.02) + (account.Balance-Threshold) * 0.03);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return (decimal)(account.Balance * 0.02);
        }
    }
}
```

In your service with

```
BankAccount account = ...;
IInterestCalculator calculator = (account.AccountType == AccountType.Premium)?new PremiumAccountInterestCalculator():DefaultAccountInterestCalculator();

BankAccount account.CalculateInterest(calculator);
```

Now your `BankAccount` class only has one responsibility, maintaining it's state and the business logic required for this (i.e. check if there is enough balance, only allow manipulation of the bank account through methods rather than directly changing `Balance` or manipulating the `List<Transaction>`.

And the calculation is done by the calculator classes, which are passed to the `BankAccount`'s `CalculateInterest` Method. The service contains the logic required which neither fits into Calculator nor BankAccount class.

So in short: Business logic (in a rich domain model) is all logic required for the class to maintain it's state and encapsulate it as much as possible. In second class it's not possible to change the balance directly. Either `AddTransaction` is required or `CalculateInterest` (for interest calculation) is required.

This guarantees (assuming it's *concurrent-safe*) that `Balance` and `Transactions` will always be in consistent state (i.e. never missing to add either Transaction or update balance).

Comment: in this example. Why an account should to know that it is needed to calculate interests, bonifications and other things? Isn't would be better the account only could increase and decrease the money that it has and to be a service or something external who calculates how much increase or decrease the amount of money and call a increase() method of the account?

Answer (score 0):

I have some soccer tournament management software written in php (not exactly the pinnacle of oop),

My business logic includes a standings calculator which figures out what position a team came in based on the results of their games.  The tie breaking strategies can be a bit involved.  Other business logic includes game scheduling, referee assigning and volunteer coordination.

This logic sits in what I consider to be the domain layer.  My entities themselves (games etc) tend to be anemic.  Just not much for them to do except hold data.  But that's fine with me.  It's the service classes where the real work comes in.

I make use or the bounded context and aggregate root concepts.  My game entity includes teams, officials and a field.  When I am in the game context then the game is king and is in charge of it's children.  In a field management context, the field is the boss and the games are just along for the ride.

I achieve persistence independence. I can model my domain entities and value objects to reflect the domain requirements without worrying about what tables they will end up in.  The ORM layer takes care of the mapping and allows me to store one domain entity across multiple tables or vice versa.

The point is, pick the stuff out of DDD that helps your particular applications.  Don't worry about the rest.